# How convert blob data type into R data type (character or logical)

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I am reading data from database using *odbc* driver. I try to use *dplyr* syntax:

```
df <- tbl(con, tbl_name) %>%
    select(...) %>%
    filter(...) %>%
    collect()
```

But most of fields from tbl_name marked as *blob* type. I know some of them is character (starts with zeros and marked as blob[16 B], some logical (marked as blob[1 B]). Can I convert them to the R data type for manipulate?

Also one field have datetime type. I want to use it in filter  - what date type I must to use in expression?  I use `'2020-01-01 00:00:00'`, `as.POSIxt()` - not work.

Comment: may you share short version of your data `dput` or `str` of the `tbl(con, tbl_name)` would be helpful

Comment: Yuriy, I don't know of any way to intelligently help here: we know nothing about the schema, the DBMS, or the output of `df`. It could be several different things. While I recognize that you cannot give us access to your db, there has to be a lot more context for us to be able to reproduce *something*. Some good hints on how to make questions more reproducible include: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Good luck!